# Change Width of Layout in A Certain Component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-ng-class, angular-ng

Is it possible that you change the width of your layout in a selected component only? I wanted to change the `<div class="page home-page">` only in my login component? Only in login component and not on other components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directives can be the solution of your problem.

**src/app/width.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[width]' })
export class widthDirective {

    @Input()
    set width(width: number) {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.width = `${this._width}px`;
    }

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {}
}
```

Then in any component you can use :

```
<div class="page home-page" width [width]="500">
```

If you want make your directives accessible anywhere you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505392/how-to-declare-a-directive-globally-for-all-modules-in-angular-2/46457114#46457114).

Comment: How can i do this. calc(100% - 200px)?

Comment: You can move your `calc` function inside the `WidthDirective` and do something like `@Input()
    set width(width: number) {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.width = \`${this.calc(100% - width)}px\`;
    }` it depends `calc()` return value, can you show me the function ?

Answer (score 1):

All styles (except the main global stylesheet) in Angular 2/4 are encapsulated, so when you're including stylesheets like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-name',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.css']
})
```

All styles from `component.css` will be applied ONLY to `component.html` (if you doesn't use things like `/deep/` and the same). So feel free to change the width of current layout, it will not affect other layouts!

Comment: However my div class="page home-page" is found on other component. How can you call the div class="page home-page" on the login component and set its width to what you want?

Comment: @Joseph, if it's in another component, you can't get access to it from current `component.css` file. You can write global styles in `styles.css` file (it's somewhere near the root of the project).

Comment: @Commerical Suicide. Yes, I applied the div class="page home-page" design on the styles.css and i want to change its width only on the login.component. Only on the login.component and not on other component

Comment: @Joseph, just add new rule to `login.component.css` and this rule will be applied only for this layout. Or may be I don't fully understand your goal.